# Check each element of a column against vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I need to check each element of a column in one data against each element of the second dataframe and when there is a match copy something from a different column in the second dataframe back to another column in the first dataframe.

Here is some fake data to play with:

```
df1 <-data.frame(c("267119002","257051033",NA,"267098003","267099020","267047006"))
names(df1)[1]<-"ID"

df2 <-data.frame(c("257051033","267098003","267119002","267047006","267099020"))
names(df2)[1]<-"ID"
df2$vals <-c(11,22,33,44,55)
```

Basically what I want to do is for each `ID` in `df1`, check for the corresponding matching row in `df2`, and copy the value of df2$vals back to `df1`. Merge is not really an option cause in the real data I need to repeat this for many columns and multiple merges would result in `df1` getting stupidly big. I need to keep it lean! And `df1` may contain `NA`'s in which case I want to place `NA` in the new column instead of a value.

Comment: perhaps using `library(data.table)`: `dt1 <- data.table(df1); dt2 <- data.table(df2, key="ID"); df3 <- as.data.frame(dt2[dt1])`?

Comment: Isn't that just a merge by another name ?

Comment: yes, seems I didn't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to agstudy's answer I was able to figure this out myself.This does exactly what I want!

```
    fetcher <-function(x){
       y <- df2$vals[which(match(df2$ID,x)==TRUE)]
       return(y) 
    }

    sapply(df1$ID,function(x) fetcher(x))
```

Thanks for the inspiration agstudy

Comment: Why not just `df2$vals[match(df1$ID,df2$ID)]`?

Comment: It didn't work in my real data set for some reason - I actually can't remember why and I've deleted the code. Also it will give me a whole bunch of columns back that I don't want and causes problems for me because I am dealing with variable numbers of columns each time a run the custom function I am writing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match`:

```
 df2[match(df1$ID,df2$ID),]

        ID vals
3  267119002   33
1  257051033   11
NA      <NA>   NA
2  267098003   22
5  267099020   55
4  267047006   44
```

ANd if you want to remove `NA`:

```
 df2[na.omit(match(df1$ID,df2$ID)),]



     ID vals
3 267119002   33
1 257051033   11
2 267098003   22
5 267099020   55
4 267047006   44
```

Comment: Did you read the whole question ? I don't want to use merge. In fact I cannot -as the ID's are not unique and may include many NA's

Comment: @user2498193 Indeed. I haven't read all the question. I edit my answer  using `match`.

Comment: Ehh works in the toy dataset but not in my real data :(

Comment: Ok I think I have it - your match idea gave me a clue - will post as solution